# How to reload data into image listbox itemtemplate? Takes to long

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-4.0, itemtemplate

I have three Buttons options that retrieve data from db and sets datacontext to ListBox, since I added an image to the ListBox ItemTemplate each time I click a different menu option, takes way to long to refresh items. Images are between 15KB and 45KB, and loaded locally. Already tried, VirtualizingStackpanel="Recycling" didn't work, maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How many items are there in your listbox ? Do you have any grouping in your listbox ?

If not then you may have to look at the datavirtualizaton in wpf.Please check the links below for more

http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=338

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/98090161-0abf-4799-bbcb-852dcc0f0608

Comment: I am displaying about 20 items. The problem here is when I refresh and reload data from db into the ListBox. Once items are displayed there is no problem browsing them. Anyway the links helped a lot! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the default ItemsPanel to a VirtualizingStackPanel?

Comment: Set item template to stackpanel and didn't work, should I use a background worker?

Comment: setting template to stackpanel will remove virtualization and make things even worse

Comment: `poindexter12` is talking about setting `ItemsPanelTemplate` to `VirtualizingStackPanel`.